# Click different icons into a div that it already have a click event

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a problem with a clickable div.

It's an Ionic 2 audio application. And I have a list of divs with different icons into them.

More exactly, each div contains two icons that can be clicked, one to download the audio and another to play it.

I need to click on each icon, perform the appropriate behaviour for each of them, but in turn, when clicking on any other part of the containing div, it must have the same behaviour as the play button, so that it plays the audio.

The problem is that if I attach the event click to the parent div, this cancels me the other events of the children icons. So when clicking on the download or play icon, it always plays the audio, because I'm really clicking on the parent div.

This is my code:

```
<div class="audioItem" ion-item *ngFor="let audio of audios" (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
            <img id="leftIcon" src="img/audio-magenta@300x.svg">
            <h3>{{ audio.name }}</h3>
            <div *ngIf="audio.downloaded">
                <img class="downloadIcon" src="img/download-onclick@300x.svg" (click)="clicked(audio)">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!audio.downloaded">
                <img class="downloadIcon" src="img/download@300x.svg" (click)="clicked(audio)">
            </div>
            <div id="play" *ngIf="!audio.locked">
                <img id="arrowIcon" src="img/play@300x.svg" (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="audio.locked">
                <img id="lockIcon" src="img/ui-lock100.png" (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
            </div>
</div>
```

Note that the clicked() method is only for test something, here it will be any other "download()" method. The important here is to know how to allow clicking the children icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also solve this issue by using `event.stopPropagation();`.

Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aVKzdS?p=preview).

like you can see there, you can also send the `$event` object to both methods

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="open($event, item)">
        {{ item }}
        <ion-icon (click)="download($event, item)" item-right name="download"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And then use that information to stop the propagation of the event, so only the right method will be executed

```
public open(event, item) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Open ' + item);
  }

  public download(event, item) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Download ' + item);
  }
```

Comment: I didn't know about it. I solved it by applying relative and absolute positions with css, something much more farfetched, as I said in my own answer below ... but I think your way to solve it is much better, thank you very much !!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

```
<ion-list>
        <div class="audioContainer" *ngFor="let audio of audios">
            <div class="audioItem" ion-item (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
                <img id="leftIcon" src="img/audio-magenta@300x.svg">
                <h3>{{ audio.name }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="audio.downloaded">
                <img class="downloadIcon" src="img/download-onclick@300x.svg" (click)="clicked(audio)">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!audio.downloaded">
                <img class="downloadIcon" src="img/download@300x.svg" (click)="clicked(audio)">
            </div>
            <div id="play" *ngIf="!audio.locked">
                <img id="arrowIcon" src="img/play@300x.svg" (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="audio.locked">
                <img id="lockIcon" src="img/ui-lock100.png" (click)="tryToPlay(audio)">
            </div>
        </div>
</ion-list>
```

Css:

```
.audioContainer {
    position: relative;
}

ion-list .audioItem {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-bottom: .1em !important;
    padding-top: .5em !important;
    padding-bottom: .5em !important;
}

ion-list .audioItem img#leftIcon {
    width: 9% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
}

ion-list img#arrowIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4%;
    bottom: 22%;
    width: 10%;
}
ion-list img#lockIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.3em;
    bottom: 1.6em;
    width: 3%;
}

ion-list img.downloadIcon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 22%;
}
```